# I have trouble identifying this display. I don't want to damage it since it's perfect for a project I have in mind

Tags: microcontroller, lcd

This is the picture of the display. It's from a toy laptop with counting games for children.[image: The display on the back of it there's tw o capacitors]

[image][image: A photo of the toy laptop.]
On a closer look it might be a toy that is mass produced for the eastern market. Any information is welcome.

Comment: how do you know it's perfect if you don't know what its interface requirements are?

Comment: It's probably some undocumented custom thing. Save yourself a whole lot of trouble and buy a well documented display for your project.

Comment: Does the toy laptop still work? Your best bet for figuring out the pinout and control sequences is to operate it while monitoring signal pins with a scope.

Answer (score 1):

If there is an integrated circuit on the other side of the board, that might give a clue as to how to interface to the liquid crystal display.  This integrated circuit that drives the display may be a clue.

Using the size (length x width) of the display and searching the LCD displays on vendor websites (for example Digi-key) may also help you find the part number and data sheets.